# On the characteristics of an Ergodic process.

Tags: stochastic-processes, ergodic-theory

Let us assume that a stochastic process, $\{X[n], n=1, 2, \ldots\}$, is ergodic.
Then, it is well known that
$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N f(X[t]) \longrightarrow \mathbb{E}[f(X)]\tag1\label{eq1}$$
with probability $1$ (or can be expressed as *almost surely*) as $N$ goes to infinity.

I have already seen the above result several times in many papers. For example, in the wireless communication system whose channel model follows an ergodic process, an infinitely long-term time average of something (e.g., data rate, power, etc.) is replaced equivalently with the average over the channel.

However, most papers do not provide an exact proof of this.
Also, in stochastic process textbooks, they only say that a stochastic process, $\{X[n], n=1, 2, \ldots\}$, is ergodic if the following statement holds: $$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N X[t] \longrightarrow \mathbb{E}[X].\tag2\label{eq2}$$

How can I prove \eqref{eq1} from \eqref{eq2}?

Comment: Any book on Ergodic Theory proves these basic results. You can look at Peter Walter's book, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean Ergodic theorem given in (1) is how it is usually stated in my experience (See e.g. wikipedia).

Here is a document that goes over the formulation of the ergodic theorem and gives an elegant proof for $L^2$-integrable functions due to von Neumann.

https://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/charles.walkden/magic/lecture05.pdf

For the general ergodic theorem requiring only $L^1$ integrability of $f$ see Durrett - Probability: Theory and Examples.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a valuable link.

Comment: In the PDF, $T:X\to X$ is introduced as a measure preserving transformation. Is it correct if I understand that $T^n$ represents $X[n]$ in random process field? (As an engineering student, the notation and terms are very challenging.)

Comment: I believe that given a base probability distribution $P_0$ (the distribution of $X_0$), one can define $T^n P_0$ (as a push forward measure). Then, $T^n P_0$ represents the distribution of $X_n$.

Comment: Its either that or $X_n := T_n(X_0)$ for a base random variable $X_0$. I am not sure.